# Ignoring outbound indices access to matrix

Tags: matlab

If I have an array A of a large size, and I have to iterate on it and get sums of part of it, is there any matlab library function to get expressions like sum(A(-5:5)) for example to just return sum(A(1:5)) instead of error, and without adding if conditions? (or treat the outbounds elements like they are zeros)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To treat outbound element as zeros, delete the index from the accessing. I assume you have a longer index range and variable indexes, else you'd just do `1:5`, right?

```
for ii: some_array
   index=-5:5; %I assume you fill this differently
   index(index<1 || index>size(A,1))=[] % delete out of bounds
   sum(A(index))
end
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would do it:

```
A = [10 20 30 40]; % example, 1D
ind_start = -5;
ind_end = 5;
A2 = A(max(ind_start,1):min(ind_end,end));
```

gives

```
A2 =
    10    20    30    40
```

Then you can apply `sum` or whatever function to `A2`.

This works with *N*-dimensional arrays too. The [`end`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/end.html) function used within an index nicely takes care of the appropriate size:

```
A = [10 20 30 40; 11 21 31 41]; % example, 2D
ind_start = -5;
ind_end = 5;
A2 = A(:, max(ind_start,1):min(ind_end,end));
```

gives

```
A2 =
    10    20    30    40
    11    21    31    41
```

Comment: nice! I think I still like my version more :P, its more explicit

Comment: And more general. Mine is only for a colon index